# Reputation cap can be bypassed by having question marked as answer after cap is hit?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I reached the reputation cap yesterday towards the end of the SO day. However, before the day lapsed, the answer (which caused the rep to cap, though I don't think that's relevant) was accepted, causing another 15 points to accumulate. By that time, I had hit the cap, but I still got those 15 points, making my total for that day 215.

You can see my profile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153498/nasufara?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time).

Is this intended, or a bug in the cap system?

Comment: Accepted answers and bounties are [immune to the reputation cap](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation cap rules:

- **Accepted answers** are never susceptible to the reputation cap (no matter when in the day they are received).
- **Bounties** may exceed the reputation cap since apparently they are also immune.